# How To Handle Two-Finger Tap Event ? WPF

Tags: wpf, events, multi-touch

In my program I would like to make two different things, one with the single touch, second with the two finger touch. But I don’t know how to handle the difference between single touch and two finger touch.

What should I do to achive that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UIElement has the ManipulationStarted event. The ManipulationStartedEventArgs has a property named Manipulators (IEnumerable). The count of Manipulators is the number of contacts being used (e.g. 2 elements would mean 2 fingers).

Also available is the ManipulationDelta event. The args there also has a Manipulators property.